# Is there an inequality on the maximum of subgaussian random variables of different variance factors?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $v_1,...,v_N$ be positive real numbers. I would like a (preferably sharp up to a universal constant) bound on $\mathbb{E}(\max_i Z_i)$, where $Z_1,…,Z_N$ are real-valued random variables such that or every i=1,…,N, the logarithm of the moment-generating function of $Z_i$ satisfies $ψ_{Z_i}(λ)≤λ^2v_i/2 $ for all λ>0.

The following is a statement from  Concentration Inequalities: A Nonasymptotic Theory of Independence(Stéphane Boucheron,Gábor Lugosi,Pascal Massart) and is similar to what I am looking for, but assumes that every random variable has the same variance factor.

Let $Z_1,…,Z_N$ be real-valued random variables where a v>0 exists such that for every i=1,…,N, the logarithm of the moment-generating function of $Z_i$ satisfies $ψ_{Z_i}(λ)≤λ^2v/2 $ for all λ>0
Then $\mathbb{E}(\max_i Z_i) \leq \sqrt{2v log(N)}$

Comment: The $Z_i$ are uniformly sub-Gaussian with parameter $v := \max\{v_1,\dots, v_n\}$. This won't be a sharp upper bound though.

Comment: Thank you. I had already worked this out, but it wasn't sharp enough

Answer (score 1):

Check out  Exercise 2.5.10 of Vershynin, "High-Dimensional Probability". I believe this is what you are looking for.

To summarize the result, let $\Vert \cdot \|_\psi$ be the "sub-Gaussian norm" or "Orlicz norm", which takes the form
$$
\Vert X\|_\psi = \inf_{t>0} \  t \ \ \text{subject to} \ \ \mathsf{E}\left\{ \exp\left(\dfrac{X^2}{t^2}\right) \right\} \leq 2.
$$
This norm is essentially how Vershynin discusses the parameters (or as you say, variance factors) of sub-Gaussian random variables; check Definition 2.5.6. to see his treatment and how it relates to other characterizations of sub-Gaussian variables.

Now, for your problem, define $ K := \max_{1 \leq i \leq N} \Vert Z_i \Vert_\psi$. You can show (see the aforementioned Exercise and the below discussions) that for every $N\geq 2$ we have
$$
\mathsf{E}\left\{ \max_{1 \leq i \leq N} |Z_i| \right\} \leq CK\sqrt{\log(N)},
$$
where $C$ is a universal constant factor.

See the below discussions you may find useful:

- [Upper bound of expected maximum of weighted sub-gaussian r.v.s](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3039181/upper-bound-of-expected-maximum-of-weighted-sub-gaussian-r-v-s)
- [Expected maximum of sub-Gaussian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3131805/expected-maximum-of-sub-gaussian)